# error of Knight go patrol

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm learning C++ and my code has errors that i do not know?

Knight go patrol
    //enter code here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#define maxn 10

void ThuNuocDiTiepTheo(int i, int x, int y, int *q);
void InBanCo(int n);
void XoaBanCo(int n);

int BanCo[maxn][maxn];
int dx[8] = { 2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2 };
int dy[8] = { -1,-2,-2,-1,1,2,2,1 };
int n = 8;


void ThuNuocDiTiepTheo(int i, int x, int y, int *q) {
    int u, v, *q1;
    int k = 0;

    do {
        *q1 = 0;
        u = x + dx[k];
        v = y + dy[k];

        if ((u >= 0) && (u < n) && (v >= 0) && (v < n) && (BanCo[u][v] = 0)) 
        {
            BanCo[u][v] = i;
            if (i < n*n) {
            ThuNuocDiTiepTheo(i+1,x,y,q1);
            if (*q1 == 0) {
                BanCo[u][v] = 0;
            }
            else {
                *q1 = 1;
            }
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }

    } while ((*q1 == 0) && (k < 8));

    *q = *q1;
}

void XoaBanCo(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1;j++) {
            BanCo[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void InBanCo(int n) {
     for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (BanCo[i][j] < 10) {
                cout << " " << BanCo[i][j];
            }
            else { 
                cout << " " << BanCo[i][j];
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void main() {
    int *q = 0;
    cout << "Nhap vao kich thuoc ban co: ";
    cin >> n; cout << "\n";
    XoaBanCo(n);
    cout << "\n";
    BanCo[0][0] = 1;
    ThuNuocDiTiepTheo(2,0,0,q);
    cout << "In ra ban co: ";
    InBanCo(n);

    system("pause");
}
```

this is error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C4700   uninitialized local variable 'q1' used

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
void ThuNuocDiTiepTheo(int i, int x, int y, int *q) {
    int u, v, *q1;
    int k = 0;

    do {
        *q1 = 0;
```

You're declaring a pointer `q1`, but it's pointing to some random memory, because you haven't initialized it.

The line `*q1 = 0;` writes a 0 into this random memory location.

You need to allocate memory for that integer, and later deallocate it, using the [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) operators.

Note that managing memory like this is not a good idea, as there are better and safer ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int u, v, *q1;
> ```

None of those variables are initialised.

> ```
> *q1 = 0;
> ```

`*q1` attempts to dereference an uninitialised pointer to which you have also not assigned a value afterwards. This causes **undefined behaviour**.

Your variable names are completely nondescript, and your function names are in a language I do not even recognise, so it's impossible to know what you intend to do here. However, even without that knowledge, the one advice I can certainly give you is: Do not use a pointer. Refactor everything to use `std::vector`.